# Place a call using TAPI from Delphi

Tags: delphi, tapi

I need to initiate a call using TAPI from Delphi 2006. I'd like it to be as simple as possible. Any suggestions for a simple component? Is it in JEDI?

Comment: The official TAPI documentation is really all you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734273(VS.85).aspx But there might be simplified wrappers around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [TurboPower Async Professional](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/), some time ago I used this library and worked perfect, you can find more info about tapi and the AsyncPro component in this [link](http://tpapro.sourceforge.net/ApdTapi.html).

Comment: I used this library for TAPI a while ago and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of components some freeware some shareware

http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=199

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use Tapi and delphi all you need is 2 things.

a. import the dll and create the tlb file.
   in the delphi menu, go to componenets, then choose import components, then choose import type library, type "tapi3" and pick the tapi3.dll.

b. with the dll created to make a call you simple need to use

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Request:ITRequest;
  dispatch:ITDispatchMapper;
begin
  Request := CoRequestMakeCall.create;
  Request.MakeCall('555-5555','Tag','client name','Comment');
end;
```

and replace the '555-5555' with the user input file number, as string.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before the `implementation`

```
function tapiRequestMakeCallW(DestAddress: PWideChar; AppName: PWideChar;
  CalledParty: PWideChar; Comment: PWideChar): LongInt; stdcall;
external 'TAPI32.DLL';
```

after that call `tapiRequestMakeCallw` like that

```
TapiSonuc:=tapiRequestMakeCallw(Phone,'', comment, Comment);
```